# MySQL gives me "unknown column" error on Windows

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have the following query executed on Node.Js using MySQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.uid) AS usersCount, COUNT(*) AS workingDaysCount
    FROM (
    SELECT d.date, u.id AS uid,
        CASE TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, SUBDATE(d.date, WEEKDAY(d.date)), d.date)
            WHEN 0 THEN w.monday
            WHEN 1 THEN w.tuesday
            WHEN 2 THEN w.wednesday
            WHEN 3 THEN w.thursday
            WHEN 4 THEN w.friday
            WHEN 5 THEN w.saturday
            WHEN 6 THEN w.sunday
            ELSE NULL
        END AS working_day
    FROM (
    SELECT date_range.date
    FROM (
        SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL (sign.a * (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * e.a) )) DAY AS date
        FROM (SELECT -1 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS sign
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS e
        ORDER BY date DESC
    ) date_range
    WHERE date_range.Date BETWEEN DATE('2021-06-10') AND DATE('2021-06-10')) d, users u
        LEFT OUTER JOIN working_days w ON w.id = (
            SELECT id
            FROM working_days
            WHERE user_id = u.id AND week_start_date <= d.date
            ORDER BY week_start_date DESC
            LIMIT 1
        )
    WHERE u.id IN (4)
    GROUP BY d.date, u.id
) t
    WHERE t.working_day = 1;
```

On Linux Server it works fine so I don't get where the problem is, but on Windows I have the following error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'd.date' in 'where clause'
```

I've looked into the code and debugged for hours, but I didn't found any answers regarding to this. Does anyone have any ideas please?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I see no definition for the table alias `d`.  MySQL would agree with this, I should note.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I guess this should work like an alias `WHERE date_range.Date BETWEEN DATE('2021-06-10') AND DATE('2021-06-10')) d, users u`

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_! Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT t.uid)` to make code clearer.

Comment: The `LEFT OUTER JOIN`'s `ON` clause only has access to `u` and `w` columns. This is what happens when you mix explicit `JOIN` and implicit, comma separated join. Switch to explicit `JOIN` everywhere, and the problem is gone!

Comment: BTW, probably your Windows MySQL version is newer than the Linux one, and the behavior has been corrected.

Comment: @jarlh what should I change exactly in order to run in without error?

Comment: Try `d JOIN users u LEFT OUTER JOIN working_days w...`, might work on MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The problem point is in combining cartesian by a comma and JOIN.

The subquery aliased as `t` looks like

```
SELECT ...
FROM (...) d, u LEFT OUTER JOIN working_days w ...
```

The comma priority is less then JOIN priority, hence the query is

```
SELECT ...
FROM (...) d, ( u LEFT OUTER JOIN working_days w ... )
```

i.e. `u` and `w` are joined firstly. Of course, the subquery `d` is not accessible in this moment.

Replace a comma with CROSS JOIN:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (...) d
CROSS JOIN u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN working_days w ...
```